# Create sprite renderer using custom material

Tags: unity, sprites, texture-atlas, materials

I have done following thing.

1. Create Material
2. Attach sprite with texture type as Texture
3. Add sprite renderer component to game object
4. Assign material to it that I create in last steps

There is no sprite available for selection. Following image illustrate my problem correctly.

[image]

So my question in how to create sprite renderer with custom material?

Comment: The sprite needs to have texture type 'sprite', doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put a Sprite asset in the Sprite Renderer "Sprite" field. And you can assign any Material on "Material" field. You don't need to put a texture on the Material.

Comment: I get some knowledge from it.